# WPF .Net v4.7.2 worrying difference between running in debug and direct

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I was using .Net 4.0 and now I have updated to .Net 4.7.2. I have noticed very worrying problems.  The program now behaves differently when running from the Visual Studio (2012) debugger or running from the `ex`e directly.

These are two problems I have noticed that don't happen with the debugger but do happen when running from the `exe`:

1. A `DataGrid` column that had `"*"` to use the remaining width just shows the column the minimum width to hold the data.
2. Page `Loaded` events are only fired sometimes.  This seems to be affected by the amount of working being done when displaying the page.  Like if there is too much work it just does not bother firing the event.

Anyone else having this or know why?

---

More info on this.  I have discovered it is always firing the Page Loaded event but it was before I had subscribed to it.

So what this means is that in debug things are happening at a different speed to direct running causing things to happen in a different order - race condition.

Comment: Are you running the exe using the same configuration (debug, release?)

Comment: Microsoft fixed problems, doesn't mean they didn't create new ones.  Do you get same issues running without VS?   The new version of VS use more resources so that may be why the issue 2 is occurring.  Curious if same issue is just running the exe without VS.

Comment: its not uncommon that under debug which is slower you see less clashes of resources, or that the debugging slows things so that B takes long enough that A is done before it is ready, but under release its  more optimized and B can happen before A is done..

Answer (score 1):

They introduced a new allocation algorithm in 4.7 to prevent infinite loops that ocurred during the layout of a `Grid` under some circumstances. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.7-4.7.1) for more information.

You can disable the new algorithm by adding a switch to your `App.config` file:

```
<runtime>
  <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Controls.Grid.StarDefinitionsCanExceedAvailableSpace=true" />
</runtime>
```